# Excel - cell matching

Tags: excel-2013

If the Value in column c matches the value in column A, then the value in the corresponding value in D should reflect in Column B

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite understanding you -- Are you saying you want to reflect the value of column D in column B if C and A are equal? And what if they're not equal?

Comment: see, i have only three values in Column C but that will be repeating continuously in the Column A. if the value in column C matches the value in Column A, corresponding value in Column D should reflect in Column B. in the image i have manually entered the values in column B, just to show what i am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with VLOOKUP formula like this:
[image]

Produces result almost identical to your sample:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, Nope, the only 3 cells in the Column C will have the values, I don't want to drag it downward. its is not A1 = C1 match , it should be C1 = any cell in Column A

Comment: Updated to reflect your clarification above. (Though note I've read your correction/comment as "A1 should match any cell in column C" as opposed to what you wrote, since your sample otherwise would have no values for rows 4 - 7 and would produce a different value for the lookup, while interpreting it the way I did now makes the output match your sample and correctly populate rows 4 -7 as well.)